# Buscador de patrones

Tags: java, c#

Vuelvo a formular una pregunta que hice unos días atrás.
La intencion es hacer un programa que genere una plantilla como la de la imagen abajo mostrada de manera "inteligente". Es decir un generador de secuencias que variará en función de los valores para las S, E o A.
Quisiera pediros ayuda para que me orientaseis como enfocar el tema para empezar a programarlo.
La verdad es que tengo poca experiencia programando y no se por donde empezar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. ¿Los valores para S E A de donde salen? ¿Son generados de manera aleatoria?

Comment: La pregunta sigue (igual que la anterior) estando fuera de tema en el sitio, ya que no tiene una respuesta única y es demasiado amplia. Pero por darte una pista, te recomiendo que busques información sobre _seleccion aleatoria ponderada_ (_random weighted selection_ en inglés),que creo que es el algoritmo que te interesa aplicar en tu caso.

Comment: Por otro lado, no debes repetir la pregunta. Es mejor que edites tu pregunta anterior y amplies la información lo máximo posible.

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias por las respuestas y perdón por no saber las reglas de esta comunidad o la Buena práctica del sitio. Intentaré adaptarme.

Comment: @Ferni Los valores son inventados, aunque al final saldrán de una BBDD. No son aleatorios, son valores de producciones diarias y van variando , semanalmente/Mensualmente.

Comment: No te preocupes, nadie nace sabiendo :) Es bueno que leas si no lo has hecho [ask]

Comment: Si la fuente de los datos aleatoria no es lo que buscas, que es exactamente? Que quieres decir con plantilla? Una imagen, un formulario con controles en una aplicación de escritorio, una vista web....?

Comment: @Alpha75 Lo que busco es poder generar una secuenciacion proporcional a los datos que yo le ponga. Ej: De un total de 150  unidades  ( que yo le digo), quiero que se reparta 80 "S", 30 "E" y 40 "A" y esta secuencia me la escriba en un txt por ejemplo.  Igual saldría SEASASEASAESA....... y esto llevarlo a un txt.  Lo único es que no pueden ir seguidas Todas las SSSSSEEEEEAAAAA juntas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si esto te orienta para que empieces. Aunque lo puedes hacer de mil formas distintas y en cualquier plataforma yo te lo enfoco a .Net con lenguaje C#.

**Secuencia**

Para generar la secuencia te propongo que te crees algún objeto que encapsule el tratamiento de tus datos de tipo S, E y A. Por ejemplo:

```
// Enumerado con los tipos posibles
public enum TipoDato
{
    S,
    E,
    A
}

// Clase que trata los datos S, E y A
public class SEAData
{
    private int  S { get; set; }
    private int E { get; set; }
    private int A { get; set; }

    public SEAData(int s, int e, int a)
    {
        S = s;
        E = e;
        A = a;
    }

    public List<TipoDato> GetSEAList()
    {
        List<TipoDato> seaList = new List<TipoDato>();
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i++)
        {
            seaList.Add(TipoDato.S);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < E; i++)
        {
            seaList.Add(TipoDato.E);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        {
            seaList.Add(TipoDato.A);
        }
        return seaList;
    }

    public List<TipoDato> GetSEAListRandom()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<TipoDato> seaList = GetSEAList();
        return seaList.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Para su uso podríamos hacerlo así:

```
private void Test()
{
    SEAData sea = new SEAData(74, 39, 71);
    List<TipoDato> sequence = sea.GetSEAListRandom();
}
```

La variable sequence te crea una lista alterada de forma aleatoria de la forma que querías.

Puedes hacer las pruebas que creas oporturnas hasta este punto.

**UI**

Siguiendo con .Net te sugiero que crees un proyecto nuevo de tipo Windows Forms y para empezar te crees un nuevo formulario (o usa el que se crea de forma automática al crear un proyecto nuevo) para hacer pruebas. Más adelante y cuando controles más yo me crearía un control de usuario (user control) al que le pasemos un objeto de nuestro tipo `SEAData` y sea capaz de pintar la UI necesaria.

Para las pruebas yo añadiría directamente en tu formulario un control de tipo flowLayoutPanel que hace de contenedor de otros controles y que te permite organizar controles de forma automática. Asegúrate de establecer la propiedad Dock de este control en Fill para que te ocupe toda la ventana. De esta forma podemos crear de forma dinámica controles en función del tamaño de nuestra lista de `SEAData`.

El siguiente ejemplo crea una matriz de controles con el valor S, E o A en el evento Load de un formulario:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SEAData seaData = new SEAData(74, 39, 71);
    List<TipoDato> seaListRandom = seaData.GetSEAListRandom();

    foreach (TipoDato tipo in seaListRandom)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new TextBox { Text = tipo.ToString() });
    }
}
```

El siguiente paso sería pintar de un color según sea S, E o A, centrar el texo....

Espero que te sirva como primer enfoque.

Esto es lo que pinta el ejemplo que te he propuesto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por ma que sea una linda respuesta, no se debe responder a algo que no demuestra un trabajo de investigacion previo. y para colmo la pregunta estaba duplicada.

Comment: @Alpha75 Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta. Voy a empezar a provar cosas. Seguro que esta solución inicial me ayudará muchisimo.